# Apps for Office: installing app through .exe install file

Tags: ms-office, office-2013, apps-for-office

I'm creating a task pane app for Office, and was wondering if it is possible to install this app through an .exe file.

I know that the standard workflow is to make the user download it from the Office Store, but I want to install the task pane app as a bundle with some other stuff. [MSDN docs says here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123515(v=office.15).aspx) that you can publish your app to an app catalog on your own server. Is this of any help for my problem?

Thanks for your help, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to install apps for Office using an .exe.

But, if you want to deploy a task pane or content app within an organization (not using the Office Store), you can upload the app's manifest to a network file share [(create a network share catalog)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123503(v=office.15).aspx) or app catalog on SharePoint [(publish to a SharePoint app catalog)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123517(v=office.15).aspx)

...and then tell your customers to use **File** > **Options** > **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings** > **Trusted App Catalogs** to point to the file share or SharePoint app catalog URL. After doing so, your apps will be available them on the Apps for Office insert UI under "My Organization" or "Shared Folder".

Also, if you have admin access, you can use Group Policy to push down the shared folder or SharePoint catalog URL setting to users, so they don't need to use the Trusted App Catalog setting UI.

Alternatively, if it makes sense for your app scenario, you can create a default document or template, insert the app(s) into that document, save it, and then distribute the doc/template to users. Because the apps are embedded in the doc/template, they will activate when the user opens the doc, or creates a doc based on the template.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. I understand, that there is no official way to do that nor is it supported by MS. But there might be a hacky workaround. I mean hypothetically, if you can create the trusted app catalog entry programmatically, you can easily fake a network share to work with. What do you think?